# How to log connections using Amazon's RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

What do I need to do to log all connections to an Amazon RDS instance?

Right now I am using MySQL Workbench and can use it to easily look at all of the current connections.  But I really want to log this data.

I know that if I had my own server running MySQL I could edit the log setting in my.ini, but in RDS I don't have access to that, and do have any way to ssh into the instance...

Is this possible?  If so how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change some parameters of my.ini. Please see the following resources:
[How to modify my.ini parameters of an Amazon RDS instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725491/how-to-modify-my-ini-parameters-of-an-amazon-rds-instance)
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2935